# Linq query to find a string in a list of strings

Tags: c#, linq

I have this query

```
var val = from user in allUsers where currentUserTeams.Contains(user.Teams) select user;
```

where `allusers` contains each user with `Teams` object, which is a list of team id and `currentUserTeams` contains list of team id. i used above linq to find out if any of user is part of team of currentuserteams team id but does not seem to be working

Comment: How is it "not working"?  Exception?  Compiler error?  Wrong results?  Is `user.Teams` a collection or single value? Have you overridden `Equals` (and `GetHashCode` for `Team`?

Comment: I'm having a hard time understanding the description of your data model. Please post the class definition for `User` and `Team`.

Comment: `Contains` takes a single value, whereas in your query, `Contains` is taking `user.Teams`, which you say is a list of team id. I feel confused about that. How are you passing a list to `Contains`? See also https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb352880%28v=vs.100%29.aspx

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you have `ID` as Team ID property, You can use [`Enumerable.Any<TSource> Method (IEnumerable<TSource>, Func<TSource, Boolean>)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb534972(v=vs.90).aspx) to check whether any element of a sequence satisfies a condition.

```
var val = allUsers
    .Where(u =>  
        u.Teams.Any(t => currentUserTeams.Any(c => c == t.Id)
    )
    .ToList();
```

Comment: currentuserteams is a list of string does not contain team Id property is there a way to modify this to search a string I am doing it like below , but I need a linq query   foreach (User user in allUsers)
                {
                    foreach (string id in user.Teams)
                    {
                        if(currentUserTeams.Contains(id))
                            memberList.Add(id);
                    }
                }

Comment: @user3230201 can you post Team class code, How you have defined `user.Teams` is it like `string[] Teams` or `List<Team> Teams`, If `user.Teams` is string collection you can use `u.Teams.Any(t => currentUserTeams.Any(c => c == t)`

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not really clear, if you mean by :

> contains each `user` with `Teams` which is a list of `team id` and `currentUserTeams` contains list of `team id`.

and

> I used above linq to find out if any of `user` is part of team of
>   `currentuserteams` team id

**1.** That both lists contain squarely `Ids` and that you want to check if any user of the `allUsers` is part of one of the `currentUserTeams`, then you should go for :

```
var val = (from user in allUsers
          where currentUserTeams.Any(curentUserTeamId=>user.Teams.Any(teamId=>teamId == curentUserTeamId)
          select user).ToList();
```

Or

**2.** That both lists contain `Team`s and that you want to check if any of the `allUsers` is part of one of the `currentUserTeams`, then you should go for :

```
var val = (from user in allUsers
          where currentUserTeams.Any(curentUserTeam=>user.Teams.Any(team=>team.Id == curentUserTeam.Id)
          Select).ToList();
```

**Update** : Using Foreach :

```
var memberList = new List<User>();

AllUsers.Foreach(user=>
{
    user.Teams.Foreach(id=>
                      {
                          if(currentUserTeams.Contains(id)
                          {
                              memberList.Add(user);
                              Break; //Because you don't need to loop through the rest of the sequence 
                          }
                      })
})
```

Comment: how to put this in a linq foreach (User user in allUsers)
                {
                    foreach (string id in user.Teams)
                    {
                        if(currentUserTeams.Contains(id))
                            memberList.Add(id);
                    }
                }

Comment: @user3230201 check my update , note that memberList.Add(id) will return a list of Team Ids, but you need the users as I understand from the original question.